# Modern advances in combinatorial game theory

Tags: reference-request, combinatorial-game-theory, surreal-numbers

I'm going to take part in teaching a course in combinatorial game theory in the best of ONAG's spirit. I was wondering if there are interesting post-ONAG results that are worth mentioning in (a later part) of this course. In particular, I'm interested in results about:

- classification of "cyclic" partisan games (the ones that are allowed to be proper positions of itself) and their arithmetics;
- computational aspects of general or restricted game analysis, including complexity;
- non-trivial applications of existing results to game analysis, or other curious ways to analyse games (yes, I'm familiar with WWFYMP);
- state-of-the-art surreal analysis.

PS: please let me know if this is rather fitting on wiki than MO.